# Probability of 2 specific people ending up in a random group of 3 people?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, conditional-probability

18 people are being randomly selected into groups of 3. Bob and Alice want to know the chance that they would be selected to be in the group together. My first thought was to find all groups where Alice and Bob are together, and then divide that by the total number of combinations of groups. I think this idea is correct, but I'm still a little unsure. This gives 1.96% by the formula
$$\frac{n-p}{\binom{n}{k}}$$

Where $n=18$, $p=2$ ( the number of people you want to be in the same group ) and $k=3$. Can anyone verify whether my solution is correct?

Comment: The group containing $A$ has $2$ other people out of $17$. The probability that $B$ is one of those $2$ is $\frac 2{17}\approx   11.76\%$.

Comment: Your expression counts a different thing.  Specifically, you are (sort of) computing the probability that a group of $k$ people chosen uniformly at random from $n$ people contains both $A,B$.  That's not what was asked.  And your formula is not correct for general $n,k$ (the numerator is hard to understand unless $k=3$).

Comment: Yes, you have the correct answer here. Thank you for clearing it up. And yes, I understand that it wouldn't work for all problems, just this one. I edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Your expression is off from lulu's by exactly a factor of $6:$ this is because you got the answer correct for the probability of a group containing Bob and Alice being chosen uniformly from the set of all possible groups of $3$ when a single group is chosen. For any case where Bob and Alice are instead grouped together for group $n$, there's a one-to-one relation between a case like that and a case where they're chosen for the first group, so it's clear that multiplying by $6$ yields the correct result. (also, I simulated the whole thing to double-check)

Comment: Friendly tip: To verify if your solution is correct in this kind of problem, you could do a quick simulation and check if the numbers match.

Comment: Yeah, a simulation is a good idea/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that Lulu's comment represents (by far) the easiest approach to the problem.

I also agree with econbernardo's comment that proposed solutions to problems of this type can be *sanity-checked*.  That is, you will need to be able to write simple computer programs in a language like C, Java, or Python.  If you have no programming experience, then I suggest making Python your first programming language.

The (inferior) approach, that involves Combinatorics, is given below.

---

The probability will be expressed as

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$$

where

$$D = \binom{18}{3} \times \binom{15}{3} \times \binom{12}{3} \times \binom{9}{3} \times \binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{3}.$$

Let $E$ denote the computation

$$\binom{15}{3} \times \binom{12}{3} \times \binom{9}{3} \times \binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{3}.$$

Then

$$D = \binom{18}{3} \times E. \tag1 $$

---

Notice that for convenience, the denominator $D$ was computed so as to assume that people were assigned to group-1, then people were assigned to group-2, and so forth.

This means that $D$ was computed so as to distinguish between a specific group of $3$ people being assigned to group-1, and (for example) the same group of $3$ people being assigned to group-2.

Because this (convenient) method of enumeration was chosen for $D$, a consistent method of enumeration must be chosen for $N$.  This means (for example) that the situation where Alice and Bob are assigned to group-1 must be distinguished from the situation where Alice and Bob are assigned to group-2.

The number of satisfying groupings, that have Alice and Bob both assigned to group-1 is

$$\binom{16}{1} \times \binom{15}{3} \times \binom{12}{3} \times \binom{9}{3} \times \binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{3}$$

$$= \binom{16}{1} \times E. \tag2 $$

As discussed, the computation of $N$ must distinguish between Alice and Bob being sent to group-1, and Alice and Bob being sent to any of the other groups.  By symmetry, the number of assignments where Alice and Bob are assigned to group-2 (for example) is the same as the number of assignments where Alice and Bob are assigned to group-1.

Therefore, using (2) above as a starting point, you have that

$$N = \binom{6}{1} \times \binom{16}{1} \times E = 96 \times E. \tag3 $$.

Therefore, using (1) and (3) above, you have that

$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{96 \times E}{\binom{18}{3} \times E} = \frac{96}{\binom{18}{3}}$$

$$= \frac{96 \times (3!) \times [(15)!]}{(18)!} = [96 \times 6] \times \frac{(15)!}{(18)!} = \frac{96 \times 6}{18 \times 17 \times 16} = \frac{576}{288} \times \frac{1}{17} = \frac{2}{17}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Definitely me understand where I went wrong. And yes, next time I'll run a simulation, which is a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

> 18 people are being randomly selected into groups of 3. Bob and Alice want to know the chance that they would be selected to be in the group together. My first thought was to find all groups where Alice and Bob are together, and then divide that by the total number of combinations of groups.

Don't be distracted by the other sixteen people.

Just consider that you are standing Bob and Alice on two among six groups of three *places*.

You want the probability for obtaining **two from three** places in **one from six** groups, when selecting any **two from eighteen** places.

---

Alternatively: Bob will be in one group.  Alice will either be one among the **two** remaining people in that group, or will be one among the **fifteen** people not in that group.